# LSZ reduction formula for massive vector bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

> What is the precise form of the LSZ reduction formula for massive vector bosons?

The LSZ formula for scalar bosons, fermions, and photons is given e.g. in the textbook "Quantum field theory" by Itzykson & Zuber.